# Access key or secret key is null, com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentials

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, databricks

I'm using Databricks and I wanna list a bucket.

```
dbutils.fs.ls("s3://mybucket)
```

> com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from
>   any provider in the chain: [BasicAWSCredentialsProvider: Access key or
>   secret key is null,
>   com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider@56e2bc92: Unable
>   to load credentials.

I'm creating the IAM role using .net. For creating the IAM role and the Instance profile I used the next code:

```
var roleName = "test";
var profileName = "test";
var client = new AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
Policy policyDoc = GeneratePolicyDocument();    
List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag> { };
tags.Add(new Tag { Key = "jobposition", Value = jobPosition });
for (int i = 0; i < functionalGroups.Count; i++)
{
    tags.Add(new Tag { Key = String.Format("functionalarea{0}", i), Value = functionalGroups[i] });
}

try
{
    // Create a role with the trust policy
    var role = client.CreateRole(new CreateRoleRequest
    {
        RoleName = roleName,
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument = policyDoc.ToJson(),
        Tags = tags
    });
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Write(e);
}

Policy policyDoc1 = GeneratePolicyDocument1();

// Add the access policy to the role
try
{
    client.PutRolePolicy(new PutRolePolicyRequest
    {
        RoleName = roleName,
        PolicyName = "testrole2",
        PolicyDocument = policyDoc1.ToJson()
    });
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Write(e);
}

try
{
    // Create an instance profile
    client.CreateInstanceProfile(new CreateInstanceProfileRequest
{
    InstanceProfileName = profileName
});
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Write(e);
}

try
{
    // Add the role to the instance profile
    client.AddRoleToInstanceProfile(new AddRoleToInstanceProfileRequest
{
    InstanceProfileName = profileName,
    RoleName = roleName
});
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Write(e);
}
```

For generating the policies I used the next code:

```
public Policy GeneratePolicyDocument()
        {
            var client = new AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
            var statements = new List<Amazon.Auth.AccessControlPolicy.Statement>();
            var actions = new List<ActionIdentifier>();
            var resources = new List<Resource>();
            var principal = new List<Principal>();
            actions.Add(new ActionIdentifier("sts:AssumeRole"));
            principal.Add(new Principal("123123123123"));


            var statement = new Amazon.Auth.AccessControlPolicy.Statement(Amazon.Auth.AccessControlPolicy.Statement.StatementEffect.Allow)
            {
                Actions = actions,
                Principals = principal
            };
            statements.Add(statement);
            Policy policy = new Policy
            {
                Version = "2012-10-17",
                Statements = statements
            };
            return policy;
        }

        public Policy GeneratePolicyDocument1()
        {
            var client = new AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
            var statements = new List<Amazon.Auth.AccessControlPolicy.Statement>();
            var actions = new List<ActionIdentifier>();
            var resources = new List<Resource>();
            var principal = new List<Principal>();
            actions.Add(new ActionIdentifier("sts:AssumeRole"));
            resources.Add(new Resource("*"));


            var statement = new Amazon.Auth.AccessControlPolicy.Statement(Amazon.Auth.AccessControlPolicy.Statement.StatementEffect.Allow)
            {
                Actions = actions,
                Resources = resources
            };
            statements.Add(statement);
            Policy policy = new Policy
            {
                Version = "2012-10-17",
                Statements = statements
            };
            return policy;
        }
    }
```

So finally I got something to that in Amazon:
[image]

My guess is I created the Instance Profile in a bad way but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: did you attach the InstanceRole to your instance? Furthermore in the sts:AssumeRole the principal should be ec2 `"Principal": { "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"}` taken from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html. you should try doing it via the aws console first then do it programatically

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. "Principal": { "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"}